# How can I make a client-server communication in vite project?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, websocket, vite, communication

I tried the code in the [docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#client-server-communication)
and there is my code

- hot-load.ts

```
import type { ViteDevServer } from 'vite'

export default function myPlugin() {
  const virtualModuleId = 'virtual:hot-load'
  const resolvedVirtualModuleId = `\0${virtualModuleId}`

  return {
    name: 'hot-load',

    resolveId(id: string) {
      if (id === virtualModuleId)
        return resolvedVirtualModuleId
      return null
    },
    load(id: string) {
      if (id === resolvedVirtualModuleId)
        return 'export const msg = "from virtual module"'
      return null
    },
    configureServer(server: ViteDevServer) {
      server.ws.on('connection', () => {
        server.ws.send('my:greetings', { msg: 'hello' })
        console.log('send')
      })
    },
  }
}
```

index.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const msg = ref<string>()
defineOptions({
  name: 'IndexPage',
})

// client side
if (import.meta.hot) {
  import.meta.hot.on('my:greetings', (data) => {
    msg.value = data.msg
    console.log(123)
  })
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ msg }}
  </div>
</template>
```

There is 'send' msg in the vite console, but no '123' in the browser console.

[Vite console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivO5R.png)
[Browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fijt.png)

I had tried the code in official docs, but it is not work.
I want to get the msg sent from the vite server.

Comment: Reread the documentation. You're listening for the wrong event name on the client

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake. I show the wrong code in last question version. I correct it! Thank you!

Comment: I can receive the msg sent from client in server, but can't get the msg in client.

Comment: It is answered in GitHub [discussion](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/13331)